# Rectangle or Border look alike behaviour on SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I have fixed rectangle inside the report body for every page ? I am placing a tablix, after that a matrix inside that rectangle. 
I have attached pictures of my ddl design view, pdf view and desired result layout. 
So far, I have tried to use fixed tablix size by using sql insert empty row. But this way, I wasn't able to put my matrix inside it.
By simply using rectangle, since the rectangle is fixed sized and I am getting problem when my tablix has more data and it is pushing down the rectangle if I have some space below my tablix and matrix.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

[image: desired result layout]

[image: PDF print view]

[image: Design view]

Answer (score 0):

In your Report Properties, set the `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` setting to `true` and make your `Rectangle` as large as it need to be on a page.  In doing this, the tables will grow into the white space with each row and not push the bottom of the rectangle until the table is too large to fit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As you mentioned, it is continuing in 2nd page and the bottom border at the first page is cut off. Yes, because the rectangle has to continue on next page. Do you have any clue on possible other alternatives than rectangle?

Comment: @4stars  Please read my full answer.  You should use a rectangle *as well as* setting the `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` setting to `true`.  Are you saying your number of data rows is too much to fit on one page?

Comment: Precisely@imdave. That ConsumeWhiteSpace =true helps me keep for the first page. But second page and onwards, it doesn't keep the layout.

Comment: @4stars  The only way you will be able to get an enclosed border around your data is to either get very clever with your data grouping to force page breaks after a certain amount of rows (Including adding in blank dummy rows to ensure a full last page) or adding the 'border' as a background image to the report that the table sits on top of.

Comment: Alternatively, just change your design so it doesn't need the border?